# Contact form with Jquery and PHP don't work

Tags: forms

```
<?php/*    Template Name: Contact  */?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php    
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.validate.min', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/jquery.validate.min.js', array('jquery') , 3.1, true );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.form', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/jquery.form.js');
      wp_enqueue_script( 'contact', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/js/contact.js'); 
     wp_enqueue_style('contactstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/contactstyle.css');

    ?>      
    <div id="wrap">
                <form id="contactform" action="processForm.php" method="post">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="email" name="email" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="message">Message:</label></td>
                        <td><textarea id="message" name="message" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Send!" id="send" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
            <div id="response"></div>
 </div>
```

also i have the `processForm.php`

```
   <?php
    // Clean up the input values
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
            $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($_POST[$key]);

        $_POST[$key] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));
    }

    // Assign the input values to variables for easy reference
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    // Test input values for errors
    $errors = array();
    if(strlen($name) < 2) {
        if(!$name) {
            $errors[] = "You must enter a name.";
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Name must be at least 2 characters.";
        }
    }
    if(!$email) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter an email.";
    } else if(!validEmail($email)) {
        $errors[] = "You must enter a valid email.";
    }
    if(strlen($message) < 10) {
        if(!$message) {
            $errors[] = "You must enter a message.";
        } else {
            $errors[] = "Message must be at least 10 characters.";
        }
    }

    if($errors) {
        // Output errors and die with a failure message
        $errortext = "";
        foreach($errors as $error) {
            $errortext .= "<li>".$error."</li>";
        }
        die("<span class='failure'>The following errors occured:<ul>". $errortext ."</ul></span>");
    }

    // Send the email
    $to = "MY-EMAIL";
    $subject = "Contact Form: $name";
    $message = "$message";
    $headers = "From: $email";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    // Die with a success message
    die("<span class='success'>Success! Your message has been sent.</span>");

    // A function that checks to see if
    // an email is valid
    function validEmail($email)
    {
       $isValid = true;
       $atIndex = strrpos($email, "@");
       if (is_bool($atIndex) && !$atIndex)
       {
          $isValid = false;
       }
       else
       {
          $domain = substr($email, $atIndex+1);
          $local = substr($email, 0, $atIndex);
          $localLen = strlen($local);
          $domainLen = strlen($domain);
          if ($localLen < 1 || $localLen > 64)
          {
             // local part length exceeded
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if ($domainLen < 1 || $domainLen > 255)
          {
             // domain part length exceeded
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if ($local[0] == '.' || $local[$localLen-1] == '.')
          {
             // local part starts or ends with '.'
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $local))
          {
             // local part has two consecutive dots
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if (!preg_match('/^[A-Za-z0-9\\-\\.]+$/', $domain))
          {
             // character not valid in domain part
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if (preg_match('/\\.\\./', $domain))
          {
             // domain part has two consecutive dots
             $isValid = false;
          }
          else if(!preg_match('/^(\\\\.|[A-Za-z0-9!#%&`_=\\/$\'*+?^{}|~.-])+$/',
                     str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
          {
             // character not valid in local part unless 
             // local part is quoted
             if (!preg_match('/^"(\\\\"|[^"])+"$/',
                 str_replace("\\\\","",$local)))
             {
                $isValid = false;
             }
          }
          if ($isValid && !(checkdnsrr($domain,"MX") || checkdnsrr($domain,"A")))
          {
             // domain not found in DNS
             $isValid = false;
          }
       }
       return $isValid;
    }

    ?>
```

and the `contact.js`

```
  $(function() {
        // Validate the contact form
      $('#contactform').validate({
        // Specify what the errors should look like
        // when they are dynamically added to the form
        errorElement: "label",
        wrapper: "td",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertBefore( element.parent().parent() );
            error.wrap("<tr class='error'></tr>");
            $("<td></td>").insertBefore(error);
        },

        // Add requirements to each of the fields
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            message: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 10
            }
        },

        // Specify what error messages to display
        // when the user does something horrid
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: "Please enter your name.",
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required.")
            },
            email: {
                required: "Please enter your email.",
                email: "Please enter a valid email."
            },
            message: {
                required: "Please enter a message.",
                minlength: jQuery.format("At least {0} characters required.")
            }
        },

        // Use Ajax to send everything to processForm.php
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $("#send").attr("value", "Sending...");
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    $(form).slideUp("fast");
                    $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("fast");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
      });
    });
```

But the form only loading, and never sent the email. Also, o create a folder call php and put there the processForm.php but the result is the same. Any help for this? 
Thanks in advanced.

**Updates:**

**1st** I used the $.noConflict(); method with this uses:

```
$.noConflict();
$(function() 
{
    // Validate the contact form
   $('#contactform').validate({
```

but i see an 404 error page. processForm.php
**2nd:** `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` but not load the send email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code:

```
 $(function() {
        // Validate the contact form
      $('#contactform').validate({
```

WordPress loads jQuery in "no conflict" mode, meaning that the "$" symbol is not defined.

Change the "$" to the proper full "jQuery" or use a [no conflict wrapper](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers).

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
{
 // Validate the contact form
  $('#contactform').validate({ but anything cant happen.

Comment: Did you read the Codex page section Otto linked?

Comment: yes Chip Bennett

Comment: You might go back and look again. `$(document).ready(function()` is not what is recommended in that link. Instead, use `jQuery(document).ready(function($)`.

Comment: Chip Bennett i read the article, again and again. If you read the first post, i write some updates. The problem remains.

Comment: I create a custom contact form, and it is works, but i have problem with 'register form'. I will open a new subject with this. Thanks